# How to find a particular css in the code base by looking it inot the inspect option from the browser

Tags: css

When I inspected my webpage, and clicked for a particular element, which is not rendered as I wanted, I saw some faults in the Css used in the style section of the browser. How to find that particular Css in the Code base.

Answer (score 0):

You should see, in addition to the CSS and the warning about a fault, an indication of which file that CSS came from.

For instance in this trivial example:

```
<style>
body {
  background: rubbish;
  }
</style>
<body></body>
```

I saw:

[image]

Notice that to the right of the faulty CSS is the file which it came from.

Search in that file for the CSS that is causing a problem